# Unable to perform insert/update/delete

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I want to use a transaction manager in my application using Hibernate and JPA.
I started by configuring **applicationContext.xml** (I also want to use c3p0 but i'll configure it later):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="dao,business" />
    <!-- Configuration du transaction manager -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="entity" />

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</prop> -->
                <!-- used for debug -->
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <!-- EhCache -->
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path" 
                    value="classpath:ehcache.xml</prop> -->
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop> -->
                <!-- configuration pool via c3p0, see https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureTheC3P0ConnectionPool -->
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop> 
                    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</prop> <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">5</prop> 
                    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">100</prop> <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</prop> 
                    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</prop> <prop key="hibernate.checkoutTimeout">1000</prop> 
                    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod">30</prop> <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 
                    1</prop> -->
                <!-- <prop key="c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</prop> -->
                <!-- <prop name="eclipselink.jdbc.bind-parameters">false</prop> -->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Configuration de la BDD -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db?autoReconnect=true" />
        <property name="username" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

My DAO look like this:

```
package dao.impl;
import dao.CategoryDao;
import entity.Category;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class CategoryDaoJpa implements CategoryDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    @Override
    public int save(Category entity) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity.getId();
    }
    @Override
    public void remove(Category entity) {
        em.remove(entity);
    }
    @Override
    public void remove(int id) {
        em.createQuery("DELETE FROM Category WHERE id=:id").setParameter("id", id).executeUpdate();
    }
    @Override
    public void update(Category entity) {
        em.merge(entity);
    }
    @Override
    public Category load(int id) {
        return em.find(Category.class, id);
    }
    @Override
    public List<Category> loadAll() {
        return em.createQuery("FROM Category ORDER BY type,sortIndex", Category.class).getResultList();
    }
    @Override
    public void update(int id, String value) {
        em.createNativeQuery("UPDATE category SET titre=:t WHERE id=:id")
                .setParameter("t", value)
                .setParameter("id", id)
                .executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

I call it in my business object:

```
package business;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import dao.CategoryDao;
import entity.Category;

@Service
@Transactional
public class CategoryService {
    @Autowired
    private CategoryDao dao;

    public void update(int id, String title) {
        Category c=dao.load(id);
        c.setTitre(title);
        dao.update(c);
    }
}
```

When I call the update(Category) function, nothing is happening :(
If I call update(int, String), I got this error:

```
Grave: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/my-app] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query] with root cause
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:333)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy156.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at dao.impl.CategoryDaoJpa.update(CategoryDaoJpa.java:53)
    at business.CategoryService.update(CategoryService.java:53)
    at controller.CategoryController.pageListe(CategoryController.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at filter.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: What happens when you remove `<prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>` from the configuration?

Comment: Do you have your code on GitHub or something? I can't think of anything else off hand that you could try, but I would like to play around with it

Comment: No, it is not versioned on an internet server. But I can make a little zip somewhere

Comment: +1 for the full stacktrace and the spring config - all elements are inside

Comment: Here is the archive if you want to try: http://yxebwoiej1.1fichier.com/

Comment: @geoand it works ?!? if yes, I'm unlucky :/

Comment: @AthaNor I will try it and let you know

Comment: @AthaNor check out my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack trace gives elements : update outside of a transaction, and `dao.impl.CategoryDaoJpa` directly injected in `CategoryService` without the transactional proxy and `CategoryService` directly injected in `CategoryController`. So the reason of the error is that spring ignores the `@Transactional` annotation on `CategoryDaoJpa` and on `CategoryService`.

First, you should set either the service or the dao to be transactional, but not both. It is more common to have the service to be transactional, because an single method of service could call many methods in dao in a single transaction.

I do not really understand why spring ignores your `@Transactional` annotations. Spring Reference Manual says : *`<tx:annotation-driven/> only looks for @Transactional on beans in the same application context it is defined in.`*. Maybe you should try to explicitely define in `applicationContext.xml` the beans that should exhibit the transactional behaviour.

Comment: I remove `@transactionnal` from my Dao and it works :)

Answer (score 3):

You should remove this:

```
<prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</prop>
```

As you already provide a Datasource, of which Hibernate is already aware of:

```
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
```

I don't see the TransactionInterceptor in your stacktrace which indicates you have no transaction available.

Also there is no proxying involved:

```
    at dao.impl.CategoryDaoJpa.update(CategoryDaoJpa.java:53)
    at business.CategoryService.update(CategoryService.java:53)
    at controller.CategoryController.pageListe(CategoryController.java:31)
```

The Service is called by the controller directly without using any proxy, like it's the case with any Spring Bean. This is why you don't see the TransactionInterceptor in your stacktrace.

How are you injecting the service in the web Controller? You should make sure you use dependency injection and not instantiate the bean manually or something.

Answer (score 3):

The problem turns out to be very subtle!

In addition to `applicationContext.xml` you have the file `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` where you configure the Web application context. 
The problem is that file you have enabled component scanning on

```
<context:component-scan base-package="dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="business" />
```

in that file.

That is clearly wrong since those beans should only be present in the root application context (and they are since you have actually enabled component scanning for those packages in `applicationContext.xml`).

What was causing the problem was that the `service` and `dao` beans from the Web application context where being used, and in that context there was no transaction manager, and there for no proxy was being created.

If you simply remove

```
<context:component-scan base-package="dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="business" />
```

from `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` then everything will work as expected because the beans from the root application context will be used (and of course will be proxied due to the existence of the transaction manager).

Comment: Thanks for your tips even if it was not solving my problem.

Comment: @AthaNor I ran it and it did solve the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it was because my filter was not `@Transactionnal`

```
package filter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
@Component //was missing
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED) //was missing
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    //no use so not implemented
    public void destroy() {
        //Ignore
    }
    @Override
    //no use so not implemented
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        //Ignore
    }
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(((HttpServletRequest)req).getSession().getAttribute("userAccount")==null) {
            HttpServletResponse response=(HttpServletResponse)resp;
            response.sendRedirect(((HttpServletRequest)req).getContextPath()+"/index.html");
            return;
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }


}
```

Comment: That is a good idea, but you are just side-stepping the real problem! What you are doing here makes every single request transactional, which is probably not what you want to be doing. Each and every request will lead to a transaction being opened, whether or not it needs to be

Comment: On my web-app I don't have background processes so every request can be transactionnal. But I agree, I have request with no query or select query so I don't need a transaction.

Comment: You probably wont see any problems immediately, but as traffic grows you might see some scalability issues

Comment: I also vote up @geoand suggestion, you should minimize the transaction length to scale better.

Comment: It is for an intranet or extranet website so if I reach 20 users, I should reconsider it. I lost already some times fixing this.